# Generating Heatmap with collcell, but with the number inside with comma

Tags: collcell

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\def\colorModel{hsb}
\newcommand\ColCell[1]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compA{(#1-90)/60}  %H
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compB{1}           %S
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compC{1}           %B
  \edef\x{\noexpand\centering\noexpand\cellcolor[\colorModel]{\compA,\compB,\compC}}\x #1
  }
\newcolumntype{H}[1]{>{\collectcell\ColCell}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{H{1cm} H{1cm}}
        98.6 & 97.7 \\
        90.2 & 99.3 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The following code generates a nice heatmap:

[image]

Someone know a possibility to show the numbers with a comma, not with a dot?

98,6 not 98.6

Comment: You could use the `siunitx` package for the printing of the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `siunitx` as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{collcell,siunitx,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\def\colorModel{hsb}
\newcommand\ColCell[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compA{(#1-90)/60}%%H
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compB{1}%S
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compC{1}%B
  \edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor[\colorModel]{\compA,\compB,\compC}}\x \num{#1}%
  }
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{H H}
  98.6 & 97.7 \\
  90.2 & 99.3 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You should take care your `\ColCell` macro does not introduce extra space.
This also works with your particular `p` format as follows

[image: p sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{collcell,siunitx,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\def\colorModel{hsb}
\newcommand\ColCell[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compA{(#1-90)/60}%%H
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compB{1}%S
  \pgfmathsetmacro\compC{1}%B
  \edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor[\colorModel]{\compA,\compB,\compC}}\centering\x
  \num{#1}% 
  }
\newcolumntype{H}[1]{>{\collectcell\ColCell}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{H{1cm} H{1cm}}
  98.6 & 97.7 \\
  90.2 & 99.3 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was missing that I must redefine my own Cell with \num{#1}. Thank you very much!